# Multiple parameters from android to nodeJS server using socket

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, parameters, server

How do I send multiple parameters on Android to a node.js sever, with the socket.emit? Im trying with `mSocket.emit("new message", username, message, String.valueOf(longitude), String.valueOf(latitude));`but it wont work. Any ideas? The android device receives messages but the webclient doesnt receive from my android.

This is the server:

```
socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data.message,
      longitude: data.longitude,
      latitude: data.latitude
    });
  });
```

This is client on the website, which is working:

```
socket.emit('new message', {
        username: username,
        message: message,
        longitude: longitude,
        latitude: latitude
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your server is expecting just one parameter (a JSONObject).
Try this code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("username", username);
jsonObject.put("message", message);
jsonObject.put("longitude", longitude);
jsonObject.put("latitude", latitude);
mSocket.emit("new message", jsonObject);
```